# enable or disable role-based authorization for Drools Guvnor 5.4.0 running on JBOSS Server 7.1.1

Tags: authentication, authorization, jboss7.x, jaas, drools-guvnor

I am using Drools Guvnor 5.4.0 Final with JBoss AS 7.1.1. Final.
I had created uses admin,krisv and guest in Guvnor with admin and guest having the Admin permission and krisv having the category permission.
Now when I log in into Guvnor I see everyone having Admin Roles including krisv. Looks like that is because I gave guest user the Admin Permission.
I removed the guest user and when I try accessing the Guvnor then I get the error - "by: org.jboss.seam.security.AuthorizationException: This user has no permissions setup." Even when I have permission setup for Admin, Krisv. I dont even get a login screen and I directly get an error. Though I have enabled Authorization enabled.
I add the guest user with category permission, say test then all users will only get to see only the assets inside this category.

Now if I dont give any rights to guest user or remove guest user I get the error mentioned above without the login screen. So I was forced to put in the guest user with certain privileges.

But then I did not see any one face this problem on the net.Any clues?

Comment: http://drools.46999.n3.nabble.com/How-configure-Guvnor-5-4-JAAS-with-jboss-7-0-2-td4020424.html

Comment: I made the change in the org.drools.guvnor.server.security.SecurityServiceImpl class which is available at the link above and it worked. I am able to log in without any Roles assigned to the Guest user.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this link.

http://drools.46999.n3.nabble.com/How-configure-Guvnor-5-4-JAAS-with-jboss-7-0-2-td4020424.html

Change the org.drools.guvnor.server.security.SecurityServiceImpl class and then my problem was resolved.